# Output from Wolfram language in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a Python program which will run a script in the [Wolfram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_%28programming_language%29) language and then return to the main program. Is it possible to return values/variables to the main program?

This is the code in Python running the Wolfram language code:

```
os.system('wolfram  -script file.wl')
```

Then in file.wl, for example, I can run a command such as 1+1, which will give me an output of 2.

Can I then use this value 2 in the rest of my Python program?

```
e.g. print (ans)
```

Comment: you might be better off asking in a python forum, seems like to need something equivalent to `ToExpression`

Comment: Thanks for help, yes I just want the output from wolfram language accessible to python

Comment: does using `Print` on the output help? Also, please don't use random tags... this question is not related in anyway to [tag:wolfram-alpha-queries] or [tag:mathematica-education]

Comment: This is on the raspberry pi and the wolfram  command runs wolfram-language. The print outputs to the command window, but after the script runs, I want the variables accessible in python.

Comment: yes, but the tag you used is for [Wolfram | Alpha](http://wolframalpha.com) (specifically, querying W|A from Mathematica) :)

Comment: @Peter Mortensen Thank you for improving my question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `os.system` command will not help you, because it does not return/provide the output of the command executed. What you want is to have a look at [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760517/1078614) to see how you can get the stdout of a command into a Python variable.

In your *Mathematica* script you simply `Print` the result and with the given method in the other answer you will fetch this result to your Python script.

Here a working example. I don't have a Raspberry Pi and therefore, the command is still good old `MathematicaScript` for me.

1. Create a *Mathematica* script file which I called `test.m` here with the following content.

   ```
   Print[1+1]
   ```
2. Create a `runScript.py` with the following content. Here I'm using the Python 2.7 function `subprocess.check_output`:

   ```
   import subprocess

   output = subprocess.check_output(['MathematicaScript', '-script', 'test.m'])
   print output
   ```
3. Run the script with something like `/usr/bin/python runScript.py`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I wasn't sure how to implement it.
 output = Popen(["os.system", "wolfram  -script gps.wl"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0] But then I get this error:                                                 
NameError: name 'Popen' is not defined

Comment: @Hamoudy You need to full specify the namespace: `subprocess.Popen` and `subprocess.PIPE` etc. Look at the last code-block in this example!

Comment: I tried, but I get no output: http://prntscr.com/2erghu

Comment: Yes you need the print otherwise nothing will be outputted

Comment: I tried it, but it shows nothing in the screen. Why?