# How to get Python bindings to work on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, python

There are several examples on this site on how to call Mathematica from Python.  You can:

- [install the bindings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4643/7167) that come with Mathematica; or
- [call a script as a subprocess](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39546/7167) from within Python; or even
- [set up a pipe](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41742/7167) and interact with it from your script.

There are some good reasons to interact with Mathematica through Python, especially since the language is [highly touted on the Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/learning-python-with-raspberry-pi/).  The Python bindings for Mathematica aren't available on the RPi version, however.  Even pulling the bindings from another installation seems to have problems.  So *how does one get Mathematica and Python to talk nicely on the Raspberry Pi*?

Comment: I've started missing the days when the questions were answered by adding `Evaluated -> True`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have an idea :-)

---

## Obtaining the code

While I've been told there's no reason not to share my findings about getting the Python bindings up and running, I wasn't given explicit permission to share the files, so I leave it up to you to find a copies of *mathlink.c* and *setup.py* which is found in the following directory (on PCs) and the comparable directory in Linux/Mac installs

```
Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\<Version>\SystemFiles\Links\Python
```

I have been successful with files from versions 8, 9 and 10.

## Organizing your RPi

You need to copy a few files and clean up your RPi to make things run smoothly.  Please note that while I've had no problems with these commands, I figure them out with trial and error.  There is likely a more elegant way to do this.

- Make sure you have `python-dev` installed (`sudo apt-get install python-dev`)
- Copy `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libuuid.so.1.3.0` to `/usr/local/lib` and rename to `libuuid.so`
- Copy `/opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/10.0/SystemFiles/Links/Mathlink/DeveloperKit/Linux-ARM/CompilerAdditions/libML32i3.so` to `/usr/local/lib`
- Run `sudo ldconfig`

## Modifying the code

A couple tweaks are needed in order to get the code to compile properly

- mathlink.c

  - Add `#define MLINTERFACE 3` at the top of the file, before the first #include line
- setup.py

  - Change the version number to "10.0"
  - You need to make sure the directories are correct and an additional library needs to be linked.  The first if statement should look like this

```python
if(re.search(r'linux2',sys.platform)):
    setup(name="mathlink", version=pythonlinkversion,
        ext_modules=[
            Extension(
                "mathlink",
                ["mathlink.c"],
                include_dirs = ["/opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/" + mathematicaversion + "/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-ARM/CompilerAdditions"],
                library_dirs = ["/opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/" + mathematicaversion + "/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-ARM/CompilerAdditions"],
                libraries = ["uuid", "ML32i3", "m", "pthread", "rt"]
            )
        ]
    )
```

## Install and test

You are now ready to build and install

```bash
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

You can test with `python -c 'import mathlink'`.  If that command throws no errors, you are in good shape.

## What to do now?

You may have noticed two other python scripts in ...\Links\Python\, a gui front end and a text front end.  Both of these seemed to work for me; however my Python programming skills are not good enough for these two programs to provide much learning assistance.  Slowly, I put together some boilerplate python code (available [here](https://github.com/bobthechemist/python-mathlink/blob/master/bplate.py)) that allows one to call a Mathematica kernel from within an interactive python session using

```bash
python -i bplate.py
```

To send an expression to the kernel, use `sendexpression("<IN>")` where  is whatever Mathematica expression you can think of. (well, almost)  Presently, I wrap everything in `ToString` so getting results is easy.  To get the result of the computation, type `getresult()`.  There's also a function `qanda()` that wraps the previous two together and saves on typing.

### What works?

Functions like `Prime`, `FactorInteger` and `GaussianMatrix` all seem to work fine.  Lists are returned as strings that must be parsed by Python. Symbols can be defined: `f[x_]:=x^2` and the kernel is aware of the system (i.e. `Directory`, `FileNames`).  We can even make `WolframAlpha` calls.  You can export graphics, `Export["test.png",Plot[Sin[x],{x,0, 4 Pi}]]` and even view them with system calls, `<<"!gpicview test.png"` although you have to be patient.

### What doesn't

Even though you can connect to the cloud via `CloudConnect[<user>,<pass>]`, `CloudEvaluate` always throws an error.  As mentioned earlier, to make this initial code easier to read, I'm returning strings so I don't have to go through a bunch of packet/token management which I don't yet understand.

### But what else does it do?

The reason why I spent time on this was to deal with a problem in using Mathematica in scripts.  On the RPi, it takes forever for Mathematica to load.  I played some games with pipes when I [tried to turn my Raspberry Pi into a Chemistry tutor](http://www.bobthechemist.com/article-categories/11-raspberry-pi/8-jasper) and now I have a better way of doing that.

If you've looked at the `bplate.py` code there's a few lines at the end that can be uncommented.  Once that's done, we can do something like this:

```bash
mkfifo mmpipe
tail -f mmpipe | python bplate.py &
```

and now we have an ever present Mathematica kernel just waiting for things to compute.  All you have to do is echo to it:

```bash
echo "Prime[10]" > mmpipe
```

Comment: @rm-rf ahh, so that's how the language is selected.

Comment: getting an incompatibility error like this on a MMA 11.2/ Ubuntu 64bit system `-Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/mathlink.o -L/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.1SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions -luuid -lML32i3 -lm -lpthread -lrt -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mathlink.so

Comment: @PlatoManiac I haven't explored this on v11 so I don't have any suggestions at this point.  Your comment references both v11.2 and v11.1. Is it possible that you have a simple path error?

Comment: Hi it was my mistake to mention 11.2. Everything was tested on 11.1 with ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, there is now a [Wolfram Client Library](https://blog.wolfram.com/2019/05/16/announcing-the-wolfram-client-library-for-python/) for Python which provides full access to the Wolfram Language from within Python.  Therefore *no mathlink craziness is needed*.  (Editorial: which is good, because trying to modify the previous answer to work with Python 3 has been a pain in the butt!)

The link above provides sufficient documentation to get one started, save for one slight modification needed to run on the Raspberry Pi.  To summarize:

Install using pip with `pip3 install wolframclient`.

Assuming the above is successful, one can now run:

```python
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl
# Explicit mention of kernel was needed here
session = WolframLanguageSession('/usr/bin/wolfram') 
# perform Wolfram operations using a string for readability
session.evaluate('RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5,0.1]]')
# perform the same operation using what the authors refer to as the wl factory
out = session.evaluate(wl.RandomVariate(wl.NormalDistribution(5,0.1)))
print(out)
```

This solution requires Python 3.5 or greater and Wolfram 11.3 or greater.  I have tested on Python 3.7.3 and  Mathematica 12.0.1 on a Raspberry Pi.  Thanks to Dorian and Arnoud for all of their hard work on this feature.